# append a new row in a different color at the end of the table

Tags: javascript, dom

**javascript**

```
function appendRow() {
    rn = window.prompt("Input number of rows", 1);

 for(var r=0;r<parseInt(rn,10);r++)
  {
   var x=document.getElementById('tbl').insertRow(r);
   }

}
```

**Questions**

1. I have a trouble adding a row at the bottom of the table.
2. Color is not getting changed

HTML

```
<style type="text/css">
.high-light{background:blue;}
</style>

    <form>
    <input type="button"  value=" append a new row " onclick="appendRow()" /><br />
    </form>
```

Comment: where is your table code?

Comment: And what "trouble" do you have exactly? Why do you expect the color to change? Have you read any kind of [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was added the table tag in html .Actually its append .Its not visible without any cell in the `row`  .Add with some cell value .add the classname at time row append

```js
function appendRow() {
  var rn = window.prompt("Input number of rows", 1);

  for (var r = 0; r < parseInt(rn, 10); r++) {

    var row = document.getElementById('tbl').insertRow(r)
    row.classList.add("high-light")
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

    // Add some text to the new cells:
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
  }

}
```

```css
.high-light {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="button" value=" append a new row " onclick="appendRow()" /><br />
</form>
<table id="tbl" border="1">


</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last row to have a different color, then just setup a condition that checks if the loop has reached the number retrieved from prompt minus 1. This will mean you have reached the last row that will be inserted, and then just set the attribute, hence:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button").onclick=appendRow;
var table = document.getElementById("tbl");
var body = document.body;

function appendRow() {
    rn = window.prompt("Input number of rows", 1);

 for(var r=0;r<parseInt(rn,10);r++)
  {
     var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
     var td = tr.insertCell();
     if (r == parseInt(rn,10)-1){
      tr.setAttribute("style", "background:green");
     }
     td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('New Cell'));
     
   }
  body.appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
.high-light{background:blue;}
```

```html
    <form>
    <input id = "button" type="button"  value=" append a new row "  /><br />
    </form>
    
    <table id="tbl" border="1">
    </table>
```

Also, if you want to append the row to the end, you've to insert `-1` as parameter to `insertRow`, ie. `insertRow(-1`)